# Have 2D sprite face 3d camera

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, coordinates

I'm creating a 3D game in Unity 5 but would like to use 2D sprites for certain parts. I'm quite new to Unity, so I might be missing something obvious. My camera's Y axis has been increased and the X axis rotated 90 degrees so that it's looking 'down' at the map. When I drag a sprite into the editor, I have to manually rotate its X axis so that it faces the camera. All the physics code then has to change slightly as the axes don't correspond to what X, Y, Z is according to the camera (instead it's according to the world).

I have to do this for every sprite, which is making me think that I'm going about this process the wrong way. Is there a way to have all sprites automatically face the camera when created or am I approaching this top-down 3D world aspect in the wrong way? Can I have the world's X, Y, Z axes defined with respect to the camera?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called billboarding (language is c#) :

```
public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cameraToLookAt;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(cameraToLookAt.transform);
    }
}
```

this will orientate any game object to face the camera. Other way to do what you want is to create a prefab/s for the sprites with the right orientation and then simply drag them into the scene.